# Is RPi 4B protected against GPIO shorting?

Tags: gpio, power, pi-4

I read that a Pi 3's +5/3V GPIO pins when they contact, potentially frying the whole computer. Does this still happen/what's the risk of this happening on a 4B? Is it "protected" in any way?

Edit - I just come back to reread this post for no reason, and almost gave myself a stroke reading the first line.

ow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi's 3V3 (pins 1/17) and 5V (pins 2/4) pins are NOT GPIO, they are part of the power supply rails.

If you connect the 5V power supply rail to the 3V3 power supply rail you will destroy the Pi.  There is no protection.

Answer (score 1):

If you only connect to header pins with the power off and/or use insulated dupont connectors there is no problem.

If you aren't using the power pins just put an insulated connector on the power pins. There is little risk using the actual GPIO pins (you have to connect 2 outputs of different levels), but even there connect with the power off.

Most people who have reported problems poke at the pins with multimeter leads - I learnt 50 years ago NOT to do this (probably the hard way).